# ¿Cómo modificar un css.map de bootstrap?

Tags: css, div, map

Buen día,

Estoy trabajando sobre una plantilla que me he descargado de bootstrab. Necesito centrar un div, el problema es que al aplicarle las líneas `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` en la hoja de estilos principal (style **.css**), no se ven reflejados los cambios a la hora de ejecutar mi *index.html*

He revisado con el *DevTools* de Chrome y me doy cuenta que las lineas de `margin-` debo agregarlas a un archivo style **.css.map**

Ya encontré los ajustes de css del DIV dentro del **.css.map** pero no sé como debo pegarlos.

Así venía originalmente el DIV en el **.css**:

```css
.mb-lg-0,
  .my-lg-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
   
  }
```

Luego le agregé los `margin`: (No funcionaron)

```css
.mb-lg-0,
  .my-lg-0 {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

Estos son los estilos con los que viene el DIV originalmente en **.css.map**

```
.mb-lg-0,\n  .my-lg-0 {\n    margin-bottom: 0 !important;\n  }
```

Nunca he trabajado con archivos .css.map

Probé haciendo esto (imaginando que los `\n` son saltos), después del `!important;` pero no funcionó :c

```
{\n margin-left: auto;\n  margin-right: auto; \n }
```

Como debo modificar una hoja **.css.map** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los archivos `.map` no son para editar o escribir CSS. Esto es lo que dice Google al respecto: [asigna código previamente procesado al código fuente](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3).

> Muchos desarrolladores generan hojas de estilo CSS usando un
>   preprocesador CSS, como Sass, Less o Stylus. Debido a que se generan
>   los archivos CSS, la edición de los archivos CSS directamente no es
>   tan útil.
>
> Para los preprocesadores que admiten mapas fuente de CSS, DevTools le
>   permite editar en vivo los archivos fuente del preprocesador en el
>   panel Orígenes, y ver los resultados sin tener que abandonar DevTools
>   o actualizar la página. Cuando inspecciona un elemento cuyos estilos
>   son proporcionados por un archivo CSS generado, el panel Elementos
>   muestra un enlace al archivo fuente original, no el archivo .css
>   generado.

También podés eliminar directamente la línea a la que llama al archivo `.map` en  tu hoja de estilos.

Podría ser así la línea que deberías eliminar, en ese caso:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Answer (score 2):

El map no te sirve para nada si no vas a editar el archivo fuente.
Lo que no deberías hacer es modificar las clases de bootstrap directamente, no esta pensado para trabajar así y lo mas seguro es que te cargues otra cosa en otra parte de la web, o que no te funcione en un determinado tamaño, o no te funcione sin mas. Debes buscar una solución dentro del propio BS. 
O al menos crear una clase nueva para interferir lo menos posible, tipo:

```
my-center{
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right:auto !important;
}
```